# Idflags is not working for setting Version for go build

Tags: go

I am fairly new to using Go and I have noticed when I build the Go project I have cloned from GitHub via:

```
$ go build
```

The executable is built, but when I run:

```
$ mediamtx --version
```

I get v0.0.0

I Googled the issue and found that I could set the Idflags parameter to set the version on build so I tried:

```
go build -ldflags="-X 'github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx/internal/core.Version=v1.5.0'"
```

Unfortunately, I ended up with the exact same problem, and *Idflags* appears to do nothing, with no errors the executable still builds. I have tried deleting and starting again from a *git clone* and running the command with *sudo*, haven't managed to get it to work, and not sure what I am doing wrong. This is what I am trying to *go build* with *Idflags* :

[MediaMTX](https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx)

This is the content of my main.go which I got my path for GitHub to include in my *Idflags* directive

```
// main executable.
package main

import (
        "os"

        "github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx/internal/core"
)

func main() {
        s, ok := core.New(os.Args[1:])
        if !ok {
                os.Exit(1)
        }
        s.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the "version" parameter in Idflags is case sensitive I was using an uppercase V "Version" when I should have been using a lower case v "version"

```
go build -ldflags="-X 'github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx/internal/core.version=v1.5.0'"
```

is the correct CLI command

Your best reference for fixing this is to refer to your core.go file to find the version variable declaration:

```
~/mediamtx/internal/core/ [main] vi core.go
```

In my case the version variable was defined as:

```
var version = "v0.0.0"
```

The issue is now resolved and:

```
mediamtx --version
```

Now outputs:

```
v1.5.0
```